# Triggering an MySql event scheduled in epoch time

Tags: php, mysql, epoch

How would I trigger a query, say, change a column state (boolean), to happen in certain epoch time using PHP?

I'm guessing it'd be something like, mysql query -> create event -> define alter

What'd be the best way to do it?

Sorry for my english, spanish speaker here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cron job or use the CREATE EVENT Syntax(available in MySQL 5.1.6 and later)

I.e.

```
mysql> CREATE EVENT yourevent
    ->     ON SCHEDULE AT '2013-02-10 23:59:00'
    ->     DO ALTER TABLE SYNTAX HERE;
```

If you want to create repeating events, you can add `EVERY interval` after `AT`([see](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html))

More information available [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)

Comment: How would I make the query using PHP but not the console?

Comment: mysql_query("CREATE EVENT...")?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a cron job to do this.
From the server you would do something like:

```
sudo crontab -u root -e
```

This would open the cron jobs for the root user for editing

Then enter the time you want the script to run, and the script you want to run

```
0 10 * * * php/foo.php
```

This would run the foo.php script every day at 10:00.